# Tool for easy file-update and restore

Tags: linux, utilities

I am looking for a commandline-tool that provides me functionality for local udating single files. So I am not talking about remotely updating a bunch of servers. But update some files and have an easy way to go back.

1. define files (like a manifest-file) to pack
2. packaging the defined files into one single archive
3. unpack that files and overwrite original files if necessary
4. backup all files that have been overwritten
5. restore the overwritten files if necessary

I think tar or some package-managers can do that but I am not sure about the
possibility of going back.

That all is not too difficunt to code it but maybe it is already here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to reinvent <s>the wheel</s> [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control).

1. “define files (like a manifest-file) to pack” — check the files in.
2. “packaging the defined files into one single archive” — the content of the files is stored in the repository.
3. “unpack that files and overwrite original files if necessary” — checking out an old version.
4. “backup all files that have been overwritten” — checking in the current version (do that before overwriting, obviously).
5. “restore the overwritten files if necessary” — checking out that other version.

Comment: Well yes but I am not talking about developing and I can not have a repo. It should have only 2 stages (what is - what should be) and switch between them. Think of it like installing an update on your system with the possibility to roll back.

Comment: Version control is not just for development... and you don't need a "repo", `git` will happily use another directory on your system.